# Matching semantic version with regex

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match semantic versions with regex where the patch (or 3rd digit) is optional.  I have most of this working, but the last, optional digits won't get matched in my group.

Example is at: https://regex101.com/r/ZuitFG/3

I'm trying to match the versions in:

```
Release 2.6 Now Live
Release 12.46.30 Now Live
Release 2.6.0 Now Live
Release 2.6.1 Now Live
```

with `/Release (\d+\.\d+[\.\d]?)/` and it just matches `x.x.` and never includes the last set of digits.  I've re-read the explanation of what this regex does several times and I'm not able to see what I'm doing incorrectly.

Comment: `[\.\d]` means "a dot _or_ a single digit" - use `(?:\.\d+)?` which is an optional non-capturing group matching a dot followed by a digit _matched 1 to infinity times_.

Comment: `[...]` always matches a single character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[\.\d]?` is an optional [**character class**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) that matches either a `.` or a digit, 1 or 0 times.

That is why only a dot was matched if there was a `.` + digit(s) sequence after two sequences of digits and dots.

You must use a [**grouping** construct](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). A [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3513858/3832970) seems the best here since it won't create any other subgroup:

```
Release (\d+\.\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
                 ^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZuitFG/5).

The `(?:\.\d+)?` matches an optional (1 or 0 times) *sequence* of `.` and then 1+ digits.